# Unchecked assignment: 'anonymous java.util.Iterator' to 'java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Integer>'

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like this

```
public class Symbol implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private int n = 123;

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {

            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {return counter < n;}

            @Override
            public Integer next() {return counter++;}

            @Override
            public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    };
}
```

I get the following warning

```
 Unchecked assignment: 'anonymous java.util.Iterator' to 'java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Integer>'
```

Now I could just ignore the warning or fill an arraylist with a for loop and return the iterator of the list but I would like to do it lazy and I would like to do it right i.e. no warnings.

Comment: Just do `return new Iterator<Integer>`

Comment: `Iterator` without the `<...>` is a raw type and you should not mix generic types and raw types.

Answer (score 4):

All you've got to do is change your anonymous class to use `Iterator<Integer>` instead of the raw type:

```
return new Iterator<Integer>() {
    // Code here as before
};
```

Imagine it had been written like this:

```
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    Iterator iterator = new Iterator() { ... };
    return iterator;
}
```

At that point the problem is clear, right? You're using a value of the raw type `Iterator` to return from a method of type `Iterator<Integer>`. Well it's exactly the same without the local variable. With the suggested change, it's equivalent to the clearly-reasonable:

```
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = new Iterator<Integer>() { ... };
    return iterator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best shot is to use a private class:

```
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new Iti();
}

private class Iti implements Iterator<Integer>{

    final int N = n;

    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {return counter < N;   }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {return counter++;}

    @Override
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to do that. It's fine to use an anonymous inner class - the OP just needs to stop using the raw type.

Comment: @JonSkeet It was the OP trying to answer himself.

Comment: @Oleg: Whoops, indeed. Not sure why it wasn't in the question as an option they'd already identified...

Answer (score 0):

Use `return new Iterator<Integer>()`.